# Can boto generate a url that is canonical to S3 bucket? Getting CORS redirect issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cross-domain, boto

Im using boto's S3 `Key.generate_url` to get a expired signed token.  This works as expected, except when used with cross-origin requests (CORS).  Since my bucket is not in the default region it will get a 307 redirect and this is making the OPTIONS request redirect and fail.  If I change the hostname of the generated url to my bucket's location ie `xxbucket-namexx.s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com` the CORS request works fine.

Any ideas of how to get this to always generate the canonical hostname for these generated URLs?

Here is how I'm generating the URL.

```
    conn = boto.connect_s3()
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('bucket-name')
    key = Key(bucket)
    key.key = 'image-name'

    signed_url = key.generate_url(
        60*5, method='PUT', policy='public-read',
        force_http=True,
        headers={'Content-Type': self.request.get('contentType'),
                 'Content-Length': self.request.get('contentLength')},
    )
```

Comment: Could you show the code you are using to create the connection and generate the URL?

Comment: @garnaat yeah, I've added an example of how Im generating the code.

Comment: What I was wondering was if you were creating a connection to the specific s3 endpoint in us-west-1 or to the generic s3 endpoint.  If the latter, try the former 8^)

Comment: @garnaat ahh, I've added that.  was just using the defaults, which grab the keys from the ENV.  Id prefer to use this code agnostic to bucket locations and have the only variable be a bucket name.  sounds like that won't be possible?

Comment: You could write your own modified version of generate_url that first checked the Location constraint for the bucket and then connected to the appropriate region.  Perhaps boto should provide a function like that but it doesn't at the moment.